# ¿Cómo incorporo datos de un JSON a un widget en Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Intento pasar datos de un json que tengo en mis assets a unos widgets pero no he podido saber cómo, considerando que el json es prácticamente una lista de mapas. Agradezco su ayuda al respecto. Adjunto los  códigos del widget principal y del json. 
En el primer Column donde esta el Text y donde esta la imagen quiero pasar respectivamente nombreProy e image (**assets/${image+**}).

En este caso necesitaría saber cómo transformar esos datos para que los pueda usar en los widgets.

```
Swiper(

    itemHeight: media.height * 0.4,
    itemWidth: media.width * .6,
    layout: SwiperLayout.TINDER,
    itemCount: 39,

    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF858585)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Familia Arkani', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Image.asset('assets/arkani.png', height: 60, width: 60,),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('pray.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                      child: Text('Orar'),
                    ),
                    Switch(
                      value: isOrar,
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState((){
                          isOrar = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],

                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('give.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                      child: Text('Ofrendar'),
                    ),
                    Switch(
                      value: isOfrendar,
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState((){
                          isOfrendar = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('move.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                      child: Text('Movilizar'),
                    ),
                    Switch(
                      value: isMovilizar,
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState((){
                          isMovilizar = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    },

    control: new SwiperControl(),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

**Este es el JSON**
Estos datos son los que quiero ir incorporando a algunos widgets

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Arkani", //aqui quiero añadir el dato nombreProy
    "image": "arkani",
    "lugar": "Asia del Sur",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Durán",
    "image": "duran",
    "lugar": "Quechua Panao",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Flores Diego",
    "image": "flores_diego",
    "lugar": "Amahuacas",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombreProy": "Fam. Garay Galvez",
    "image": "garay_galvez",
    "lugar": "Estados Unidos",
    "proceso": "En Campo"
   },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener la **clave - valor** de tu **Json**, puedes hacerlo creándote clases en **dart** para luego almacenar los datos del **Json** en los atributos de la clase creada.
Primero creas dos clases  una clase la llamaremos `Datos` y a la otra `ListaDatos`, la primera clase Datos contendrá los valores de las claves de tu **Json**, en sus atributos correspondientes de la `clase Datos`, y la `clase ListaDatos` sera un conjunto de clases Datos,así para que puedas tener mas de un objeto **Json** en tu clase.
Este es el código para las clases:

```
class ListaDatos {
  final List<Datos> dato;

  ListaDatos({
    this.dato,
  });

  factory ListaDatos.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Datos> data = new List<Datos>();
      data = parsedJson.map((i)=>Datos.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return new ListaDatos(
       dato: data,
    );
  }
}


class Datos{
  final String id;
  final String nombreProy;
  final String image;
  final String lugar;
  final String proceso;

  Datos({
    this.id,
    this.nombreProy,
    this.image,
    this.lugar,
    this.proceso,
  });

  factory Datos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> toJson){
      return new Datos(
        id: toJson["id"].toString(),
        nombreProy: toJson["nombreProy"],
        image: toJson["image"],
        lugar: toJson["lugar"],
        proceso: toJson["proceso"],

      );
  }

}
```

> Luego necesitas métodos asíncronos para obtener los datos de tu Json
>   guardado en la dirección : `assets/mi_Json.json`

```
Future<String> _cargarJson() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/mi_Json.json');
}

Future<ListaDatos> cargarDatos() async {
  String jsonString = await _cargarJson(); 
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);  
  return ListaDatos.fromJson(jsonResponse);
}
```

Luego en tu clase de tipo State:
Declaras un **Future** de tipo `ListaDatos` para obtener los datos del **Json**

```
Future<ListaDatos> lista;
```

> Luego en tu `initState()` llamas al método `cargarDatos()`:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();  

     lista=  cargarDatos();
   }
```

> Ahora lo mas interesante en tu **Widget** en la parte del **bod**y debes
>   declarar un `FutureBuilder` de tipo `ListaDatos`. La función de `FutureBuilder`
>   es utilizar un widget mientras obtiene los datos del **Json** para luego
>   mostrarlos, en este caso mostraremos un barra o circulo de carga 
>   mientras se este obteniendo los datos una vez obtenidos los datos **Json**,
>   la barra de carga desaparecerá y mostrara tu `Swiper`.
>
> Para obtener los datos del `Future<ListaDatos>` debes hacerlo de esta
>   manera: `snapshot.data.dato[0].nombreProy`.
>   Aquí te paso el widget tu utilizas los datos donde veas conveniente.

```
body:FutureBuilder<ListaDatos>(
              future: lista,  
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red[900]),),);
                }else{

                      return Swiper(
                        containerHeight: 500,                  
                        itemCount: 3,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        return Container(
                          height: 500,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF858585)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(snapshot.data.dato[0].nombreProy, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Image.asset('assets/arkani.png', height: 60, width: 60,),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 20,),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,

                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset('pray.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                                        child: Text('Orar'),
                                      ),
                                      Switch(
                                        value: isOrar,
                                        onChanged: (value){
                                          setState((){
                                            isOrar = value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],

                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset('give.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                                        child: Text('Ofrendar'),
                                      ),
                                      Switch(
                                        value: isOfrendar,
                                        onChanged: (value){
                                          setState((){
                                            isOfrendar = value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset('move.png', height: 30, width: 30,),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                                        child: Text('Movilizar'),
                                      ),
                                      Switch(
                                        value: isMovilizar,
                                        onChanged: (value){
                                          setState((){
                                            isMovilizar = value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },

                    control: new SwiperControl(),
                  );
                }
              }
        ),
```

> No te olvides de importar las siguientes librerias para que los
>   metodos async funciones y la conversion de Json a clase dart:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
```